# Need second login area for Joomla website

Tags: web, authentication, joomla

I am working on a Joomla site which currently is using the Login Form to let people register for a newsletter.  I need a way to create a second and separate Login area for stores that allows them access to a special part of the site (specific ordering form).  I can't find any answers on how to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/) for that?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repurposing the login form to sign up for a newsletter, why not use a newsletter form to sign up for the newsletter and the login form to login? The login for is generating a user token and tied in to the account confirmation code that you will likely need if you are registering users to view a special section of the site. What newsletter manager are you using? You'd be better off using a ChronoForms form in a module to handle the newsletter registration if there isn't a module specific for your newsletter manager.

Comment: The login form is also cureently being used with VirtueMart, not sure if that matter because I'd still want to maintain the login functionality for the online store.  Which is separate from the second login area I'm trying to create.

Comment: Further clarification, currently the Mass Mail is being used to send out the emails. (They aren't so much newsletters as just simple text emails.  Sorry for the poor explanation to start with)

Comment: Using a newsletter manager is better than using Mass Mail since it allows users to manage their accounts more effectively. Also, they will generally be better at throttling and sending mass mails as the size of the list grows. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter. Since VM uses the Joomla user table, you would need to code a new component that has its own user table if you want to have independent user access levels then you will either need components that have their own user tables or you will need an extension that manages user access like ACL.